# How To add * in Textbox Starting value and print into label in C#

Tags: c#

I have some `text boxes` in my form where the user need to enter the different prices of article, what I want to do is to automatically add Starting value `*` whenever text is changed . So when the user types `1` it is displayed like `*****1` 
and text box Length are `6` size fix. then again user type `111` it is display like `***111`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PadLeft` method for a string:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.PadLeft(6, '*');
```

See an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPfFsx

Comment: Thanks Sir you are Good.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are on web, forms or what, but here is what you looking for:

```
txt1.Text = txt1.Text.PadLeft(6, '*');
```

Reference: [PadLeft](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj947P9m-rTAhXCDZoKHTTJA6wQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.string.padleft(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHu9Dq3VuH2jqA2KXSlx2RXepjNpQ&sig2=WXVgrg-M0QfvSaLVpICwsQ)